# Pack 4 textures into one channel

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, hlsl

Can I pack 4 grayscale textures into one channel by converting the textures into uints and packing them?

```
uint b1 = (t1.r * 255 & mask1) << 0;
uint b2 = (t2.r * 255 & mask2) << 8;
uint b3 = (t3.r * 255 & mask3) << 16;
uint b4 = (t4.r * 255 & mask4) << 24;
t.r = b1 | b2 | b3 | b4;
```

"mask#" is a uint with 1s for #th byte and 0s for all other bytes. "t#" is a grayscale texture.
"t" is the texture we are packing into.

My main concern is that t.r is a float, and I'm not allowed to access the bits.

Comment: Which graphics API and shader language are you using? That may affect what your options are.

Comment: can you post your shader code ?

Comment: I thought single color channel only have single byte data . so maybe no , can not save 4 byte data in a single byte.

Comment: Although `t.r` is `float` in C# , but texture still only save one byte data in one channel.

Comment: @TimChang so would it be possible to pack 2 floats into a single channel?

Comment: You can have int32 or float32 textures, though they take up as much memory and texture sampling bandwidth per channel as the 4 byte channels you're packing, so this may not be a net win. Keep in mind though that a 32-bit float has only 23 bits of mantissa, the rest are exponents and sign, so you can't pack/unpack them the same way you pack an int. Also note that a packed colour channel won't compress, interpolate, or filter properly.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm making a texture2DArray at runtime. I was thinking of packing the height and smoothness into the alpha (it's gonna be pretty low res). As for the interpolation, maybe I could use derivatives to calculate something?

Comment: Is the end usage in the vertex shader, the pixel shader or code on the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work? I'm not test it.

```
    byte mask1 = 0;//0~4
    byte mask2 = 0;//0~4
    byte mask3 = 0;//0~4
    byte mask4 = 0;//0~4

    byte maskCombine = (byte)((mask1) & (mask2 << 2) & (mask3 << 4) & (mask4 << 6));
    Color32[] colors = new Color32[4];
    colors[0].r = maskCombine;
    Texture2D t = null;
    t.SetPixels32(colors,0);
```

shader:

```
half alpha = mask.r;
half mask1 = step(0.25 , alpha-0.75);// here get 0 or 1
half mask2 = step(0.25 , alpha-0.5);
half mask3 = step(0.25 , alpha-0.25);
half mask4 = step(0.25 , alpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast the floats  to `uint` after multiply. `float` is only good to 21 bits, so use an `uint32` type as the output:

```
uint b1 = (uint(t1.r * 255) & oxFF);
uint b2 = (uint(t2.r * 255) & 0xFF) << 8;
uint b3 = (uint(t3.r * 255) & 0xFF) << 16;
uint b4 = (uint(t4.r * 255) & oxFF) << 24;
uint packed = b1 | b2 | b3 | b4; 
Tex.rgba = packed;
```

If `float`s were used there would be round trip loss in b1 and the lsb bit of b2, by `Ceil(log2(ReverseBitOrder(b1)) + Ceil(log2(b4)))` bits.

Make sure you use an uncompressed format without mip maps for perfect channel recovery.

So make `Tex` an integer format: convert the textures to use GL_RGBA32 instead of GL_RGBA32F for OpenGL or DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT instead of DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM for Windows depending on platform.